# Lost Nodes In Red Black Tree

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-search-tree, nodes, red-black-tree

I was writing a code for a Stock Trading platform prototype. I opted for a Red Black Tree to store the transactions. I was writing the code for an RB-Tree with the keys as the tradeValue(3rd element in the parameter list). When inserting the keys in this particular order [80, 9, 4, 3, 2 (descending order) the last 2 nodes seem to get lost.

Below is the code for the data structure. I have followed the implementation given in 'Introduction to Algorithms' on pg. 439. I have also included helper functions to print and visualise the tree.

```
def getTradeValue(transaction):
    return transaction[1] * transaction[2]

RED = True
BLACK = False

class RBTree:

    def __init__(self, transaction):
        self.key = getTradeValue(transaction)
        self.value = [transaction]
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        self.color = RED

    def isRed(self):
        if self is not None:
            return self.color

    def rotateLeft(self):
        rotatedTree = self.right
        self.right = rotatedTree.left
        rotatedTree.left = self
        rotatedTree.color = self.color
        self.color = RED

        return rotatedTree

    def rotateRight(self):
        rotatedTree = self.left
        self.left = rotatedTree.right
        rotatedTree.right = self
        rotatedTree.color = self.color
        self.color = RED

        return rotatedTree


    def colorFlip(self):
        self.color = RED
        self.right.color = BLACK
        self.left.color = BLACK


    def put(self, transaction):

        if self is None: return RBTree(transaction)

        if getTradeValue(transaction) == self.key:
            self.value.append(transaction)

        elif getTradeValue(transaction) < self.key:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = RBTree(transaction)
            else:
                self.left.put(transaction)

        elif getTradeValue(transaction) > self.key:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = RBTree(transaction)
            else:
                self.right.put(transaction)

        if (self.right and self.right.isRed()) and (self.left and not self.left.isRed()): self = self.rotateLeft()
        if (self.left and self.left.isRed()) and (self.left.left and self.left.left.isRed()): self = self.rotateRight()
        if (self.left and self.left.isRed()) and (self.right and self.right.isRed()): self.colorFlip()

        return self

    def inorder(self):
        if self:
            if self.left:
                print(self.left.inorder())
            print(self.key, "  ", self.value, "  ", self.color)
            if self.right:
                print(self.right.inorder())

    def print2DUtil(self, space) :
        COUNT = [10]
        # Base case
        if self is None :
            return

        # Increase distance between levels
        space += COUNT[0]

        # Process right child first
        if self.right:
            self.right.print2DUtil(space)

        # Print current node after space
        # count
        print()
        for i in range(COUNT[0], space):
            print(end = " ")
        print(self.key,self.color)

        # Process left child
        if self.left:
            self.left.print2DUtil(space)

bst = RBTree(["", 1, 80, ""])
bst.color = BLACK

bst = bst.put(["", 1, 9, ""])
bst.color = BLACK
# bst.inorder()
# print("--------")

bst = bst.put(["", 1, 4, ""])
bst.color = BLACK
# bst.inorder()
bst.print2DUtil(0)
print("--------")

bst = bst.put(["", 1, 3, ""])
bst.color = BLACK
# bst.inorder()
bst.print2DUtil(0)
print("--------")

bst = bst.put(["", 1, 100, ""])
bst.color = BLACK
# bst.inorder()
bst.print2DUtil(0)
print("--------")

bst = bst.put(["", 1, 17, ""])
bst.color = BLACK
bst.print2DUtil(0)
# bst.inorder()
print("--------")

bst = bst.put(["", 1, 2, ""])
bst.color = BLACK
# bst.inorder()
bst.print2DUtil(0)
print("--------")


# bst.print2DUtil(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix for the bug:

In the put function-

change `self.left.put(transaction)` to `self.left = self.left.put(transaction)`

change `self.right.put(transaction)` to `self.right = self.right.put(transaction)`